# pygame collision detection with walls

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Currently I've been spending around half an hour trying to figure out how to implement this script better. I've tried a few methods, but they didn't quite work.
When running the script, the player glitches a bit, and sometimes the player can only move in the blocks once it comes in contact.

```
x = 64*3
y = 0
xvel = 0
yvel = 0
grounded = True

playerRect = pygame.Rect ((x, y, 64, 64))

collidelist = []

level = ["#=======##=========================",
         "#=======#==========================",
         "#==###############=========###=====",
         "#===============#####==============",
         "#==================================",
         "###################################"]

def makelevel (level):
    x = y = 0
    def checkline (line, x, y):
        for character in line:
            if character == "#":
                block = pygame.draw.rect (screen, (50, 50, 255), (x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64))
                collidelist.append (block)
            x += 1
    for line in level:
        checkline (line, x, y)
        y += 1
def move (xvel, yvel):
    global x
    global y
    global playerRect
    global collideList
    x += xvel
    y += yvel
    for block in collidelist:
        if playerRect.colliderect(block):
            x += -xvel * 2
            y += -yvel * 2
            break
makelevel (level)

while True:
    screen.fill ([0, 0, 0])
    makelevel (level)
    playerRect = pygame.Rect ((x, y, 64, 64))
    pygame.draw.rect (screen, (255, 255, 255), playerRect)
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit ()
            exit ()
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed ()
    if pressed [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        move (5, 0)
    if pressed [pygame.K_LEFT]:
        move (-5, 0)
    if pressed [pygame.K_UP]:
        move (0, -5)
    if pressed [pygame.K_DOWN]:
        move (0, 5)
    pygame.display.update ()
```

Comment: The blue blocks are supposed to be walls, right? The simplest way to detect and handle wall collisions is to move the rect along the x-axis first, check if it collides with a wall rect and then set the `playerRect.right` to `block.left` or vice versa depending on the direction. Then you do the same with the y-axis and set `playerRect.bottom` to `block.top` if they collide. That means you have to iterate over the `collidelist` twice.

Comment: I'm afraid that that didn't work, or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong? `x += xvel
    for block in collidelist:
        if playerRect.colliderect(block):
            if playerDirection == "Right":
                playerRect.right = block.left
            if playerDirection == "Left":
                playerRect.left = block.right
    y += yvel
    for block in collidelist:
        if playerRect.colliderect (block):
            if playerDirection == "Up":
                playerRect.top = block.bottom
            if playerDirection == "Down":
                playerRect.bottom = block.top`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle collisions with walls, the easiest solution is to move the player rect or sprite along the x-axis first, check if it collides with a wall and then set its `rect.right = block.left` if we're moving to the right or `rect.left = block.right` if we're moving to the left. Afterwards you do the same with the y-axis. We have to do it separately, otherwise we wouldn't know the direction and how to reset the position of the rect.

Here's an example:

```
import sys
import pygame


def makelevel(level):
    collidelist = []
    for y, line in enumerate(level):
        for x, character in enumerate(line):
            if character == "#":
                block = pygame.Rect(x*64, y*64, 64, 64)
                collidelist.append(block)
    return collidelist


def move(xvel, yvel, player_rect, collideList):
    # Move the rect along the x-axis first.
    player_rect.x += xvel
    # Check if it collides with a block.
    for block in collidelist:
        if player_rect.colliderect(block):
            if xvel < 0:  # We're moving to the left.
                # Move the player out of the block.
                player_rect.left = block.right
            elif xvel > 0:  # We're moving to the right.
                player_rect.right = block.left
            break

    # Now do the same for the y-axis.
    player_rect.y += yvel
    for block in collidelist:
        if player_rect.colliderect(block):
            if yvel < 0:
                player_rect.top = block.bottom
            elif yvel > 0:
                player_rect.bottom = block.top
            break


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
BLOCK_COLOR = (50, 50, 255)
BG_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

level = ["#=======##=========================",
         "#=======#==========================",
         "#==###############=========###=====",
         "#===============#####==============",
         "#==================================",
         "###################################",]

collidelist = makelevel(level)
player_rect = pygame.Rect((64*3, 0, 64, 64))
# A clock to limit the frame rate.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        move(5, 0, player_rect, collidelist)
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        move(-5, 0, player_rect, collidelist)
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        move(0, -5, player_rect, collidelist)
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        move(0, 5, player_rect, collidelist)

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)

    for rect in collidelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLOCK_COLOR, rect)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), player_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit frame rate to 30 fps.
```

There were some other issues with your code that I need to address (even though codereview is offtopic (check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)):

- The most severe problem is that you call `makelevel` in your main loop, so you append more and more rects to the `collidelist` until you run out of memory. Create the list inside this function and then return and assign it to a variable above the while loop and just reuse it.
- It's also not necessary to define the `checkline` function inside of `makelevel`.
- Global variables can have a bad effect on the comprehensibility and maintainability of the code. Rather pass the needed variables to the functions that need them and return the results.
- Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of incrementing `y` and `x` by 1 in `makelevel`.

Comment: You're a legend! I haven't tried this, due to being on holiday, but it looks like it'll work!